# Deriving field equation in Yang Mills theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, yang-mills

Trying to show that
$$D_\mu\vec{F^{\mu \nu}} = \partial_{\mu}\vec{F^{\mu \nu}} + g \vec{A_\mu} \times \vec{F^{\mu \nu}} = 4 \pi \vec{J^\nu},$$

or (correct me if I'm wrong) $$ \partial_{\mu} F^{\mu \nu}_a + g f_{abc}A_\mu^bF ^{c\mu \nu} = 4 \pi J^{\nu}_a.$$

by varying the action

$$S= \int \left( \frac{-1}{4}F^a_{\mu \nu} F_a^{\mu \nu} +J_a^\mu A_\mu^a \right) d^3x dt$$

I know how to do this for regular E&M (starting directly with the Euler-Lagrange equations actually), but not sure how to deal with that extra term arising from the operator $D_\mu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The covariant differential operator $D_\mu$ is $D_\mu = \partial_\mu (Id)- ig A_\mu =  \partial_\mu (Id)- ig T^a A_\mu^a$, where $(Id)$ is the identity matrix and the $T^a$ are the generators of a Lie algebra.

You have $F_{\mu\nu} = D_\mu A_\nu  - D_\nu A_\mu$, which means that $F_{\mu\nu}$ is a covariant quantity.

From the expressions above and the commutation relations $[T^a, T^b]=i f^{abc}T^c$ definining the Lie algebra, you get  the expression of $F_{\mu\nu}^a$:

$F_{\mu\nu}^a  =\partial_\mu A_\nu^a - \partial_\nu A_\mu^a + g f^{abc}A_\mu^b A_\nu^c$.

Now just apply Euler-Lagrange equations $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial A_\nu^a} - \partial_\mu \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu  A_\nu^a)}=0$.

Comment: If I want to explicitly write out $F^a_{\mu \nu} F _a^{\mu \nu}$ would the first term be
$\left( \partial_\mu A^a_\nu - \partial_\nu A^a_\mu + g f^{abc} A^b_\mu A^c_\mu \right)$ ?
What about the second one, with upper indices?
Can I write $\left( \eta^{\mu \gamma} \partial_\gamma A_{\delta a} \eta^{\delta \nu} - \eta^{\nu \rho} \partial_\rho A_{\sigma a} \eta^{\sigma \mu} + f^{abc}  \eta^{\kappa \mu} A_{\kappa b}  \eta^{\lambda \nu} A_{\lambda c}    \right)$? 
Also, is f here the Levi Civita tensor? Struggling with index notation, sorry.

Comment: @user44212 : 1) You obtain "contravariant" quantities $A^\mu_a$ from "covariant" quantities $A_{\nu a}$ by using the metric tensor : $A^\mu_a = \eta^{\mu\nu}A_{\nu a}$. 2) $f^{abc}$ is a completely antisymmetric tensor characteristic of the Lie algebra. In the special case where the Lie algebra is $su(2)$, $f^{abc} = \epsilon^{abc}$, the Levi Civita tensor $(a,b,c)$ in $(1,2,3)$